# how to overload the += operator with the operands of different types (if possible)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Instead of having an add() method in the repository, I would like to overload the += operator so that the expression

```
_repository += myModel;
```

will insert myModel into the database(after i submit changes)

I know that the objects of different type cannot be used in operator overloading. Still want to know if there is some alternate ways to accomplish this

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would *strongly, strongly* urge you not to do this even if you can. It goes against how operator overloading is meant to be used - what would you return from your operator? A new "clone" of the repository, or just `this`?

A generic method is the way to go here. Just say "no" to overusing operator overloading.

Comment: Ya, we have to return something here. But i want in such a way that myModel is just added to the datacontext, but return nothing which would be same as the Add() method. Just curious to know why the usage of operator overloading in this context is not encouraged

Comment: Because it's not obvious what it means. It might make sense for you (now..), but as you saw Jon didn't "get" what you expect this to do, what this does at all right away. It's a safe bet that your coworkers will agree and shake their head, wondering what's going on there.

Comment: The fact that you don't *want* to return anything but that the operator makes it act as `_repository = _repository + myModel` should be a good indication that it's not a good fit.

Comment: That's fine. One more question. Do you also say creating an indexer for the repository is a bad idea?(for retrieving the model using primary key)

Comment: Something like this: MyModel myModel = _repository[8]; instead of _repository.GetMyModel(8);

Comment: @Veer: If the repository *only* includes instances of MyModel, that makes sense. If it has different types, then you can't really do it easily.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I find this answer problematic for two reasons: one is that in some use cases (e.g. immutable repositories, with the intention of returning a new repository identical to the original one except that it also includes the newly added model) overloading `+` and `+=` is actually arguably an elegant API for the operation, and the other, more important one, is that regardless of the validity of the content it's not an answer, and should have been a comment. (I've added my own answer, which I think addresses the issues.)

Answer (score 0):

> I know that the objects of different type cannot be used in operator overloading.

I'm not sure what you mean by that. You can, for example, make an `operator +` inside the repository type which takes two parameters, one of the repository type and one of the model type.

As to overloading the `+=` operator, there's no way to do that directly; rather, you get that as a side effect by overloading the `+` operator (see [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading)).

So the solution is to make `operator +` of a repository and a model return the new repository (the original one with the model provided added), and that will make `+=` have the desired effect as well.

**NOTE:** If what you do is return a *new* repository that is like the original one but with the new model added, then this seems a reasonable way to go about it. If, however, what you mean for this is to *mutate* the original repository, then this would lead to unidiomatic, misleading code, as you will need `+` to change the repository just as if it was `+=`!